# Finding the 'Run As' value for each job step in a SQL job

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am trying to find the 'Run As' value used in each job step for all jobs in my instance. I am able to find owner of the jobs using below query but not the above value. Please help

```
USE msdb

SELECT *
FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobs_view J
LEFT JOIN master.dbo.syslogins L
    ON J.owner_sid = L.sid
LEFT JOIN [msdb].[dbo].[syscategories] AS [sCAT]
    ON j.[category_id] = [sCAT].[category_id]
WHERE J.enabled = 1
```

Comment: Have you set run as to use a proxy account? If so, `msdb.dbo.sysjobsteps` has a column called `proxy_id` which links back to `msdb.dbo.sysproxies`. From there you can link to the SQL Server login by connecting `user_sid` from the proxies table to `master.sys.server_principals.sid`. Also, you shouldn't be using deprecated, backward compatibility views like `syslogins`.

Comment: After some modifications it helped :)

Answer (score 1):

After stitching together a couple of the notes from the comments and answers, I came out with the following script when trying to answer this same question on my own environment:

```
USE msdb
GO

SELECT
    JobName    = j.name
   ,StepNumber = js.step_id
   ,StepName   = js.step_name
   ,ProxyName  = p.name
FROM
    dbo.sysjobsteps js
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
    dbo.sysproxies  p ON
        js.proxy_id = p.proxy_id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
    dbo.sysjobs     j ON
        js.job_id = j.job_id
ORDER BY
    j.name
   ,js.step_id
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the T-SQL form of an answer, inspired by the comment made by @Aaron Bertrand below the question. In particular, `dbo.sysproxies` holds the ProxyName values.

In practice, I don't use the `select *`, but rather specifically name the fields to be selected. In this case I named `sp.Name` to illustrate where the "Run As" value is shown.

```
SELECT sp.NAME AS ProxyName,
    *
FROM dbo.sysjobs_view J
LEFT JOIN sys.syslogins L
    ON J.owner_sid = L.sid
LEFT JOIN dbo.syscategories AS [sCAT]
    ON j.[category_id] = [sCAT].[category_id]
LEFT JOIN dbo.sysproxies sp
    ON l.sid = sp.user_sid
WHERE J.enabled = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT 
       sysjobsteps.step_name, 
       sysjobs.name 
 FROM sysjobsteps , sysjobs
 WHERE proxy_id = (SELECT proxy_id FROM msdb.dbo.sysproxies WHERE (name = 'ProxyAccountName'))
 AND sysjobs.job_id = sysjobsteps.job_id
```

Comment: You need to be more descriptive.